# dynamically reference property of self in python

Tags: python, django

I currently have a bunch of language checks in place in a python (django) function:

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):

  if translation.get_language() == 'fr':
    trans_field = getattr(instance, self.fr_field)
  else:
    return getattr(instance, self.en_field)
```

What I want to do is run this in a loop:

```
for language in languages:
  if translation.get_language() == language:
    return getattr(instance, self.[language]_field)
  else:
    return getattr(instance, self.en_field)
```

How do I do this? Obviously the `self.[language]_field` is pseudocode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getattr` a second time:

```
return getattr(instance, gettattr(self, '{}_field'.format(language))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to also assign this variable to begin with in the init function as well, i.e. `def __init__(self, en_field, fr_field, languages): for language in languages: getattr(
                    instance, getattr(self, language + '_field')) = 'body_' + language`? Right now I am declaring them statically as well: `self.en_field = en_field`, `self.fr_field = fr_field`

Comment: you can use `setattr` for that

Answer (score 2):

You already have the solution there. Use getattr
`getattr(instance, getattr(self, language + '_field'))`